# How to Place Multiple Columns Under A Single Column in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, latex

I am trying to reproduce the table in the image below in Org-mode. How do I go about doing it? Whenever I try to have multiple columns (the 'Trial' ones) under a single column (Time), Org-mode inserts blank columns to the right of Time and makes it so that all Trial columns are on their separate columns. I also need the vertical columns, I will be exporting it to a PDF with LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Org mode tables cannot do that. You might want to investigate [table.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html#Text-Based-Tables) tables, although Org mode treats them as second-class citizens (at best) - but the support might be just good enough for your needs. Alternatively, you can use raw LaTeX for things like this.

Comment: @NickD Thank you, I am looking into it right now.